# Error : Property is Read only?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have a binding source to entity :

```
MyBindingsource.Datasource = _
            (From t in context.Mytable Select t.id , t.vl1 , t.vl2).Tolist
```

Now , I try to change a value like this :

```
Mybindingsource.Current.vl1 = 25
```

I get an error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Property 'vl1' is ReadOnly.

Why I get this error ? What can I do ?

Thank you !

Comment: Did you try casting the current to the entity type? `Dim item = TryCast(Mybindingsource.Current, MyTable)` then check item.vl1.

Comment: if I try the following code everything works ok :
 MyBindingsource.datasource=(From t in context.Mytable Select t).Tolist
But I want to use my previous code .